# Determine the nature of $f(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Consider a polynomial $f(x)$ with real coefficients having the property $f(g(x))=g(f(x))$ for every polynomial $g(x)$ with real coefficients. Determine and prove the nature of $f(x)$.

Can someone help me whit this thing?

I got: if $g(x)=a, a \in \mathbb{R}$, then $f=id$. But, let's take $$f(x)=x^2, g(x)=x$$

Then $$f(g(x))=f(x)=x^2$$

$$g(f(x))=g(x^2)=x^2$$

I can't find out general results

Comment: If $f$ is supposed to satisfy that condition for _every_ $g$, then in particular it _must_ satisfy that condition for $g(x) = a$. Do you see what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

First consider the fact that $f(g(x))=g(f(x))$ is true for **every** $g(x)$. This means that we can easily find a $g(x)$ which restricts the properties of $f(x)$. To do this consider $g(x)=a$ for some real $a$. This implies $f(a)=a$. Now it easy to show that there does not exist a polynomial that preserves only constants and not unknowns. This all implies that $f$ **must** be the identity function because of the case that $g(x)=a$ that has to be handled as $g(x)$ covers every polynomial over the reals (and constant functions are definitely part of this set).